# how to do a running score animation in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation

I wish to do a running score animation for my iphone app in xcode such that whenever I increase the score by an integer scoreAdded, the score will run up to the new score instead of being updated to the new score. I try some for loop with sleep but to no available. So I'm wondering if there's any way of doing it. Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to give a lot more info if you want an answer you can use. Does your game use an NSTimer scheduledTimer call to update your game at regular intervals? How are you displaying the score, is it using UIKit? What went wrong with the for loop?

Comment: i display the score using a UILabel and pass an int currentScore to it. Then I implemented a touch class and whenever touch ended, an int scoreAdded is passed to a method that updates the currentScore. Sorry about the lack of information.

Comment: OK, I think you should add a timer. I'll stick an answer in...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a timer that will call a specific method every so often, like this:

```
NSTimer *tUpdate;
NSTimeInterval tiCallRate = 1.0 / 15.0;
tUpdate = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:tiCallRate
                                           target:self
                                         selector:@selector(updateScore:)
                                         userInfo:nil
                                          repeats:YES];
```

This will call your **updateScore** method 15 times a second

Then in the main part of your game, instead of simply adding the amount to **currentScore**, I would instead store the additional amount in a separate member variable, say **addToScore**. e.g.

```
addToScore = 10;
```

Your new method **updateScore** would have a bit of code like this:

```
if (addToScore)
{
    addToScore--;
    currentScore++;
    // Now display currentScore
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try redrawing the view after each iteration where your score is being displayed:

```
for (/* loop conditions here */) {
    score += 1;
    [scoreView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

Comment: so do i do something like 
for ( int i = currentScore; i < currentScore + scoreAdded; i++) {
score+=1;
displayScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",currentScore];
}

Comment: sorry eimantas, i sort of get your idea and should have posted my code earlier. But thanks for the help.