# How to animate incrementing number in UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, animation

I have a label showing a number and I want to change it to a higher number, however I'd like to add a bit of flare to it.
I'd like to have the number increment up to the higher number with an ease inout curve so it speeds up then slows down.
This answer shows how to make it increment (the 2nd answer, not the accepted answer) but I'd rather animate it so I could also make it increase in size slightly then shrink again as well as the ease inout curve.
[how to do a running score animation in iphone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851584/how-to-do-a-running-score-animation-in-iphone-sdk)

Any ideas how best to achieve this?
Thanks

The start/end numbers will be user inputted and I want it to increment up the the end number in the same amount of time. So if I have start 10 end 100 or start 10 end 1000 I want it to count up to the end number in say 5 seconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a flag to see if it has to go up or down.
Instead of a for loop, use a while loop.
In this way, you are creating a loop that keeps going, so you have to find a way to stop it also, f.e. by a button press.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself enough. I have added more to my question.
I can increment from 1 number to another using a for loop or a while loop. However I want it to count up by slowly speeding up then slowing down towards the end. And all to happen in a set amount of time.

Comment: Then you can use 2 for-loops :
 - One to go up
 - And one to count down

If you want to use a set amount of time, you'll have to use a timers, because otherwise, it happens as fast as the cpu can process it.

Comment: I don't need to count down. I can manage the loops, I just need to make the process happen in a certain amount of time.
Can I put the count up loop in a timer to make the process happen in that amount of time, like with an animation? I thought timers would just tell it how often to happen.

Comment: If you see the first answer off the link you posted in your question, you can see that the timer will do the loop 15 times a second. You could use two loops with a different time.

Another way is using the option `sleep(milliseconds)` in your loop. If you use a parameter for the wait time, you can decrease it via a custom algorithm. f.e. first time it runs 2000 ms, second time 2000ms - (i * 100ms), etc.

Comment: The problem with that is if I get a high number I have to count to. I wouldn't want to slow it down, i'd want to speed it up.

Comment: Then you use the reverse off what I said :
Take a start time of for example 1000ms
2nd time : 1000ms + i * 100 ms

Answer (score 77):

I actually made such a class just for this called UICountingLabel:

http://github.com/dataxpress/UICountingLabel

It allows you to specify whether you want the counting mode to be linear, ease in, ease out, or ease in/out.  Ease in/out starts counting slowly, speeds up, and then finishes slowly - all in whatever amount of time you specify.

It doesn't currently support setting the actual font size of the label based on the current value, though I may add support for that if it's a feature that's in-demand.  Most of the labels in my layouts don't have a lot of room to grow or shrink, so I'm not sure how you want to use it.  However, it behaves totally like a normal label, so you can change the font size on your own as well.

Comment: Glad you like it :) If you have any feature requests feel free to post 'em on Github!

Comment: This is a nice one but does anyone know how to get UICountingLabel to work with comma as a decimal point instead on period?

Comment: I downloaded and  tested a count from 0 to 30 in 3 seconds but did not work. The animation lasted closer to 4 seconds.

Comment: I implemented this into my own project, and it works perfectly.

Comment: Is there a swift version of this?

Answer (score 20):

Here @malex's answer in swift 3.

```
func incrementLabel(to endValue: Int) {
    let duration: Double = 2.0 //seconds
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        for i in 0 ..< (endValue + 1) {
            let sleepTime = UInt32(duration/Double(endValue) * 1000000.0)
            usleep(sleepTime)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.myLabel.text = "\(i)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I strongly recommend simply [downloading this class from GitHub](https://gist.github.com/topLayoutGuide/6aebc66d248a47588db01406059465c1) and dragging it into your project, I've resorted to using it because the timing in my code doesn't seem to adjust properly for lower/higher count numbers. This class works great and looks very good. See [this medium article](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/swift-3-so-i-wanted-to-animate-a-label-14dd2b332ef9) for reference.

Comment: I don't think that's correct.  I think sleepTime is misconfigured.

Comment: Great catch. I corrected the answer to include the duration calculation, however, in my testing, the math is correct but there's a delay in the sleep/dispatch.main process so for the code above, it takes around 4 seconds to complete instead of 2 as entered.

Comment: That gist code seems to be dead. Please update the answer. @TravisM.

Answer (score 18):

You can use GCD to shift delays to background threads.

Here is the example of value animation (from 1 to 100 in 10 seconds)

```
float animationPeriod = 10;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    for (int i = 1; i < 101; i ++) {
        usleep(animationPeriod/100 * 1000000); // sleep in microseconds
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            yourLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: When I pasted this into Xcode, I got an error over "MAIN_QUEUE". I had to replace "MAIN_QUEUE" with "dispatch_get_main_queue()". Otherwise, this a great answer.

Comment: Well thank you for posting it. The heavily upvoted UICountingLabel answer above is not working correctly anymore so this was a nice alternative.

Comment: this gives me the value straight away.. without "animating" in swift 2.0 any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

There you have it without blocking sleeps!
stick this to a UILabel and it counts up and down from the value currently displaying, cleaning non numbers first.
Adjust from Double to Int or Float if needed.

> ```
> yourlabel.countAnimation(upto: 100.0)
> ```

```
another simple alternative

extension UILabel {    
    func countAnimation(upto: Double) {
        let from: Double = text?.replace(string: ",", replacement: ".").components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: "-0123456789.").inverted).first.flatMap { Double($0) } ?? 0.0
        let steps: Int = 20
        let duration = 0.350
        let rate = duration / Double(steps)
        let diff = upto - from
        for i in 0...steps {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + rate * Double(i)) {
                self.text = "\(from + diff * (Double(i) / Double(steps)))"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is 8 years old

Comment: Simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 Code :

```
let animationPeriod: Float = 1
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async(execute: {
        for i in 1..<Int(endValue) {
            usleep(useconds_t(animationPeriod / 10 * 10000)) // sleep in microseconds
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.lbl.text = "\(i+1)"
            })
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a fast counting animation, you can use a recursive func like so:

```
func updateGems(diff: Int) {
     animateIncrement(diff: diff, index: 0, start: 50)
}

func animateIncrement(diff: Int, index: Int, start: Int) {

    if index == diff {return}
    gemsLabel.text = "\(start + index)"
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.002) {
        self.animateIncrement(diff: diff, index: index + 1, start: start)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the ones looking for a linear slow down counter (Swift 5) :

```
    func animateCountLabel(to userCount: Int) {
        countLabel.text = " "
        let countStart: Int = userCount - 10
        let countEnd: Int = userCount
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async { [weak self] in
            for i in (countStart...countEnd) {
                let delayTime = UInt64(pow(2, (Float(i) - Float(countStart))))
                usleep(useconds_t( delayTime * 1300 )) // sleep in microseconds
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    self?.countLabel.text = "\(i)"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You can change the start end points and slow down speed by changing static values to your needs ;)

Answer (score 1):

My variation of [@Sergio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6723008/sergio)'s answer:

```swift
extension UILabel {
    func countAnimation(upto: Double) {
        let fromString = text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "Score: ", with: "")
        let from: Double = fromString?.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".")
            .components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: "-0123456789.").inverted)
            .first.flatMap { Double($0) } ?? 0.0
        let duration = 0.4
        let diff = upto - from
        let rate = duration / diff
        for item in 0...Int(diff) {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + rate * Double(item)) {
                self.text = "Score: \(Int(from + diff * (Double(item) / diff)))"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So amount of steps is based on the difference between starting and ending values

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did it :

```
- (void)setupAndStartCounter:(CGFloat)duration {
    NSUInteger step = 3;//use your own logic here to define the step.
    NSUInteger remainder = numberYouWantToCount%step;//for me it was 30

    if (step < remainder) {
        remainder = remainder%step;
    }

    self.aTimer = [self getTimer:[self getInvocation:@selector(animateLabel:increment:) arguments:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:remainder], [NSNumber numberWithInteger:step], nil]] timeInterval:(duration * (step/(float) numberYouWantToCountTo)) willRepeat:YES];
    [self addTimerToRunLoop:self.aTimer];
}

- (void)animateLabel:(NSNumber*)remainder increment:(NSNumber*)increment {
    NSInteger finish = finalValue;

    if ([self.aLabel.text integerValue] <= (finish) && ([self.aLabel.text integerValue] + [increment integerValue]<= (finish))) {
        self.aLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)([self.aLabel.text integerValue] + [increment integerValue])];
    }else{
        self.aLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)([self.aLabel.text integerValue] + [remainder integerValue])];
        [self.aTimer invalidate];
        self.aTimer = nil;
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Timer related Functions

- (NSTimer*)getTimer:(NSInvocation *)invocation timeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)timeInterval willRepeat:(BOOL)willRepeat
{
    return [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:timeInterval invocation:invocation repeats:willRepeat];
}

- (NSInvocation*)getInvocation:(SEL)methodName arguments:(NSMutableArray*)arguments
{
    NSMethodSignature *sig = [self methodSignatureForSelector:methodName];
    NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];
    [invocation setTarget:self];
    [invocation setSelector:methodName];
    if (arguments != nil)
    {
        id arg1 = [arguments objectAtIndex:0];
        id arg2 = [arguments objectAtIndex:1];
        [invocation setArgument:&arg1 atIndex:2];
        [invocation setArgument:&arg2 atIndex:3];
    }
    return invocation;
}

- (void)addTimerToRunLoop:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check https://github.com/leszek-s/LSCategories

It allows incrementing/decrementing number in UILabel with a single line of code like this:

```
[self.label lsAnimateCounterWithStartValue:10 endValue:100 duration:5 completionBlock:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

### Details

Xcode 9.2, swift 4

### Solution

```
class LoadingProcess {

    let minValue: Int
    let maxValue: Int
    var currentValue: Int

    private let progressQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "ProgressView")
    private let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)

    init (minValue: Int, maxValue: Int) {
        self.minValue = minValue
        self.currentValue = minValue
        self.maxValue = maxValue
    }

    private func delay(stepDelayUsec: useconds_t, completion: @escaping ()->()) {
        usleep(stepDelayUsec)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion()
        }
    }

    func simulateLoading(toValue: Int, step: Int = 1, stepDelayUsec: useconds_t? = 10_000,
                         valueChanged: @escaping (_ currentValue: Int)->(),
                         completion: ((_ currentValue: Int)->())? = nil) {

        semaphore.wait()
        progressQueue.sync {
            if currentValue <= toValue && currentValue <= maxValue {
                usleep(stepDelayUsec!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    valueChanged(self.currentValue)
                    self.currentValue += step
                    self.semaphore.signal()
                    self.simulateLoading(toValue: toValue, step: step, stepDelayUsec: stepDelayUsec, valueChanged: valueChanged, completion: completion)
                }

            } else {
                self.semaphore.signal()
                completion?(currentValue)
            }
        }
    }

    func finish(step: Int = 1, stepDelayUsec: useconds_t? = 10_000,
                valueChanged: @escaping (_ currentValue: Int)->(),
                completion: ((_ currentValue: Int)->())? = nil) {
        simulateLoading(toValue: maxValue, step: step, stepDelayUsec: stepDelayUsec, valueChanged: valueChanged, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
let loadingProcess = LoadingProcess(minValue: 0, maxValue: 100)

loadingProcess.simulateLoading(toValue: 80, valueChanged: { currentValue in
    // Update views
})

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    print("Start loading data")
    sleep(5)
    print("Data loaded")
    loadingProcess.finish(valueChanged: { currentValue in
        // Update views
    }) { _ in
        print("End")
    }
}
```

### Full sample

> Do not forget to **add the solution code here**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var counterLabel: UILabel!
    weak var progressView: UIProgressView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
        stackView.spacing = 8
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 80).isActive = true
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -80).isActive = true

        let label = UILabel()
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.text = "0"
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 46)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
        counterLabel = label

        let progressView = UIProgressView()
        progressView.trackTintColor = .lightGray
        progressView.progressTintColor = .blue
        progressView.layer.cornerRadius = 4
        progressView.clipsToBounds = true
        progressView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 8).isActive = true
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(progressView)
        self.progressView = progressView

        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Start", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(startButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
    }

    @objc func startButtonTapped() {
        sample()
    }

    private func setProcess(currentValue: Int) {
        let value = 0.01 * Float(currentValue)
        self.counterLabel?.text = "\(currentValue)"
        self.progressView?.setProgress(value, animated: true)
        print("\(currentValue)")
    }

    func sample() {

        let loadingProcess = LoadingProcess(minValue: 0, maxValue: 100)

        loadingProcess.simulateLoading(toValue: 80, valueChanged: { currentValue in
            self.setProcess(currentValue: currentValue)
        })

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            print("Start loading data")
            sleep(5)
            print("Data loaded")
            loadingProcess.finish(valueChanged: { currentValue in
                self.setProcess(currentValue: currentValue)
            }) { _ in
                print("end")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Results

[image]